# how to get coordinates of rectangle vertices inside another rectangle?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, coordinate-transformation, affinetransform

i know this is a simple math, but I stuck. i'm using c++ opencv for image processing. I have two rectangles, and bounding box inside both of it. the problem is to get coordinates of this bounding box in original full frame.

```cpp
cv::Point2d rawTopLeft, rawBotRight; //x0,y0, x1,y1

auto rawWidth = rawBotRight.x - rawTopLeft.x;
auto rawHeight = rawBotRight.y - rawTopLeft.y;
/*
640 - is origin_width
400 - origin height
320 - small frame width
200 - small frame height
(x0,y0,x1,y1) - raw coordinates on small frame

*/
auto xScale = 640 / 320; //scales between small frame and big one
auto yScale = 400 / 200;

auto topLeft = cv::Point2d(rawTopLeft.x * xScale, rawTopLeft.y * yScale);
auto botRight = cv::Point2d(rawBotRight.x * xScale, rawBotRight.y * yScale);
```

I assume, that bounding box coordinates in original reference frame are `topLeft.x, topLeft.y, botRight.x, botRight.y`, but when I use `cv::Rectangle(topLeft.x, topLeft.y, botRight.x - topLeft.x, botRight.y - topLeft.y)` image shows wrong box. What am I doing wrong? Ty for advices.

Here is a picture explaining the problem:

[image]

Comment: Good use of the image. We don't see many of those.

Comment: Your code seems to me scales respect origin. If this isn't what you want, what's the point of the plane that shouldn't change? You mentioned a *wrong box*, can you explain what you consider *right*?

Comment: How are two frames related? Does smaller one represent some part of bigger one in other coordinates, and if so, what part and how is mapped to smaller rectangle?

Comment: @YurkoFlisk the image on the left  with a rectangle inside, has been resized to the one on the right

Comment: How exactly do you display your box? You use `cv::rectangle` function (which has different signature than how you used it in question, see [here](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html#ga07d2f74cadcf8e305e810ce8eed13bc9)) with two point arguments or with `cv::Rect`, formed from 4 values? In the first case, you pass points directly (thus no need to specify coordinates x and y separately), but in the second, beware that `cv::Rect` constructor considers last two parameters as width and height, not as coordinates.

Comment: @JeruLuke maybe, but the word 'frame' adds some confusion.

Comment: @YurkoFlisk smaller frame is resized origin frame - width and height are scaled by 0.5. And I display my box by `cv::rectangle` with width and height, which ofc are lengths of vectors represented as `x2-x1` and `y2-y1`

Comment: @JeruLuke yes it is. And I need those rectangle coordinates in left image coordinate system. All I have are: right image and information about rectangle's vertices inside small image. And width, height of both images

Comment: @MatG I expect that _right box_ (right means not wrong) will bound certain area on image, but it has some offset. cause of that I'm sure, that it's _wrong box_

Comment: Can you show full code by editing the question please (ideally providing [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example))? Resulting and desired images would also be helpful.

Comment: read the docs for `cv::Rect`. @YurkoFlisk is right, you're misunderstanding the third and fourth arguments. -- I'm surprised that this question gets such upvotes. it boils down to some subtractions and checking the docs to make sure you understood the APIs right. -- just so you don't confuse yourself, use *clear nomenclature*. stick with either "x,y,w,h" or "tl,br", and check to make sure your calculations for every step interpret your values correctly.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz sorry for that mistake in statement. but I'm using `cv::Rectangle()` constructor exactly with `x,y,width,height` parameters. I'll provide minimal reproducible example, to be clear

Comment: your post contains this: `cv::Rectangle(topLeft.x, topLeft.y, topLeft.x + botRight.x, topLeft.y + botRight.y)` and that's... not how to calculate that

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz oh, of course, you're right! width and height are `botRight.x - topLeft.x`, `botRight.y - topLeft.y`.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz ty for advices! I made it very carefully step by step in small sandbox project, and it worked! I needed to be more careful in the main project where I got confused in terms.